# Do I report the pvalue of the standardized or unstandardized factor loading in CFA/SEM?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, reporting, lavaan

Using lavaan, for a simple CFA or SEM with measurement tools, you can use `parameterEstimates(fit, standardized=TRUE)` to get the standardized factor loadings for the LV, however, the SE and p-values produced for each of the loading are still for the unstandardized estimates (this is also noted in the documentation of lavaan).

If you use `standardizedSolution(fit)` *then* you will get standardized SE and p-values.

My questions:

1. I  understand you can report both standardized and unstandardized estimates, but do you also report both versions of SE and p-values?
2. What happens/what does it mean when the two versions of p-values differ (i.e. significant when standardized, n.s. when unstandardized?)
3. I see different examples in papers and books, some show the p-values of individual loading (or use symbols with the estimates on the paths), but some don't. What's best practice?
4. Related to 3. do the p-values of the factor loadings matter? or as long as the underlying theory is sound and the overall fit is not too bad, it doesn't matter?

Comment: Unstandardized.